# ng-grid unable to edit cell

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have very simple ngGrid layout. When I try to edit a cell in cell edit mode, I can only enter one character. If I enter another character, the previous one gets overwritten.If I paste a string and then press any character it will remove the previous string and replace with a single character.
I am not sure why this is causing.

```
app.controller ('TableEditCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.myData =[{"Time":"","OldValue":"","NewValue":"", "Action" : "NoChange"}];
$scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs : [{field: 'Time' , displayName : 'Time', enableCellEdit : true}]

});

<div ng-grid="gridOptions" style="margin-top : 1%;float : left; height : 400px"></div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle will help, for now don't see a problem

Comment: Here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vrFEtZuIhPFafqfl0eU0). There is no problem in plnkr but I don't know why I am getting this in my app.

Comment: Please help. This is driving my crazy.

Comment: Plunker works for me..

Comment: I commented all my code and started uncommenting one by one. The issue didn't go away. Then created a new JS file and added my methods one by  one again. Now its working. The issue was very strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `editableCellTemplate`

```
columnDefs : [{field: 'Time' , displayName : 'Time', enableCellEdit : true, editableCellTemplate: '<div><form name="inputForm"><input type="text" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"  /></form></div>' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "enableCellSelection: true"